# Unbinding a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, bind

When a click event (for instance) is linked to an element I know how to unbind it: `$( '#element' ).unbind( 'click', whatever_function );`

But how to proceed when it's a plugin instead of an event, like:

```
$( '#element' ).sticky();
```

How to unbind/undo this ? I tried `$( '#element' ).unbind( sticky );` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.unstick()` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/garand/sticky#usage)

to stick: `$("#element").sticky();`

to unstick: `$("#element").unstick();`

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/luneju/1/edit)